# Cassandra : Update gc_grace_seconds for keyspace

Tags: cassandra, ttl

Is it possible to update gc_grace_seconds for all the tables in a keyspace? Or should it had to be done per folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in command to change table options for all tables in the keyspace, but it's easy to implement using the bash + cqlsh.  Something like this (replace `keyspace_name` and `new_value` with actual parameters):

```sh
cqlsh -e 'DESCRIBE FULL SCHEMA;'|grep -e '^CREATE TABLE keyspace_name'|\
   sed -e 's|^CREATE TABLE \(.*\) (|ALTER TABLE \1 WITH gc_grace_seconds = new_value; |'|\
   tee schema-changes.cql
cqlsh -f schema-changes.cql
```